# Set selected option based on mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML form that a user can use to edit a row in a mysql database, the PHP script queries the database and then displays the current data in form. I have this working fine for text fields with something like:

```
Correct Answer:<input type="text" name="answer" value="<?php echo $row['CorrectAnswer']; ?>"><br>
```

and simple radio set up like:

```
<?php 
            if ($row['Hazardous'] == "no"){
        ?>      
        Hazardous?:<input type="radio" name="hazardous" value="yes">Yes 
            <input type="radio" name="hazardous" value="no" checked="checked">No<br>
        <?php
            }else{
        ?>
        Hazardous?:<input type="radio" name="hazardous" value="yes" checked="checked">Yes   
            <input type="radio" name="hazardous" value="no" >No<br>
        <?php } ?>
```

I also have a select option element like below:

```
Category: <select name="category">
                <option value="hazardawareness">Hazard Awareness</option>
                    <option value="observation">Observation</option>
                    <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="attitude">Attitude</option>
                    <option value="knowledge">Gen. Knowledge</option>
            </select><br>
```

Which im trying to set up, I could use:

```
<?php if ($row['Category'] == "hazardawareness"){ ?>        
    Category: <select name="category">
                <option value="hazardawareness" selected="selected">Hazard Awareness</option>
                    <option value="observation">Observation</option>
                    <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="attitude">Attitude</option>
                    <option value="knowledge">Gen. Knowledge</option>
            </select><br>   
<?php }else if ($row['Category'] == "observation"){ ?>
Category: <select name="category">
                <option value="hazardawareness">Hazard Awareness</option>
                    <option value="observation" selected="selected">Observation</option>
                    <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="attitude">Attitude</option>
                    <option value="knowledge">Gen. Knowledge</option>
            </select><br>   
<?php }else if ($row['Category'] == "insurance"){ ?>
Category: <select name="category">
                <option value="hazardawareness">Hazard Awareness</option>
                    <option value="observation">Observation</option>
                    <option value="insurance"selected="selected">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="attitude">Attitude</option>
                    <option value="knowledge">Gen. Knowledge</option>
            </select><br>   
<?php }else if ($row['Category'] == "attitude"){ ?>
Category: <select name="category">
                <option value="hazardawareness">Hazard Awareness</option>
                    <option value="observation">Observation</option>
                    <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="attitude" selected="selected">Attitude</option>
                    <option value="knowledge">Gen. Knowledge</option>
            </select><br>   
<?php }else if ($row['Category'] == "knowledge"){ ?>
Category: <select name="category">
                <option value="hazardawareness" >Hazard Awareness</option>
                    <option value="observation">Observation</option>
                    <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="attitude">Attitude</option>
                    <option value="knowledge" selected="selected">Gen. Knowledge</option>
            </select><br>   
<?php } ?>
```

But perhaps there is a better method to do this without duplicating so much code?

Comment: Put your select options into an array and then iterate over the array to generate the options. When rendering each option check if it is the selected option and if so add the selected attribute to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `if` clause on your `option` creation that will at the `selected` attribute if needed.

```
<?php $options = array( 
                 "Hazard Awareness" => hazardawareness, 
                 "Observation" => observation,
                 "Insurance" => insurance, 
                 "Attitude" => attitude 
              );  ?>
<select name="category">
<?php  foreach($options as $display => $value) {  ?>
    <option value='<?= $value ?>' <?php if($row['Category'] == trim($value)) { ?>selected='selected'<?php } ?>>
        <?= $display ?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Went with this option as it was a little clear and the resulting code is nearly the same lines as just doing the element in html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to do the work using less code:

```
<?php
$options = array(
"Hazard Awareness" => hazardawareness,
"Observation" => observation,
"Insurance" => insurance,
"Attitude" => attitude
);
echo 'Category:  <select name="category">';
foreach($options as $display => $value) {
if ($row['Category'] == trim($value)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '" selected>' . $display .'</option>';
}
else {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $display . '</option>';
}
}
echo '</select>';
```

Put your option data in `array()`.